# How can I delete any node at random out of a Doubly Linked List in Java?

Tags: java, doubly-linked-list

I'm making a Doubly Linked List that allows you to insert at the front and rear, as well as deleting any node from the list as long as it exists. The problem is that it doesn't work and gives off and either gives off a NullPointerException or it just says That Integer does not exist even though it does exist.The code is:

```
public class Numbers {

    Node head = null; //Head of the list
    Node tail = null; //end of the doubly list    
    int size = 0;


    public void FrontInsert(int data) {
        Node n = new Node();
        if (head == null) {
            head = n;

        } else {
            n.prev = head;
            head.next = n;
            head = n;

        }
        size++;
    }

    public void RearInsert(int data) {
        Node n = new Node();
        if (head == null) {
            head = n;
            tail = n;

        } else {

            n.next = tail;
            tail.prev = n;
            tail = n;
        }
        size++;
    }

    public void Delete(int x) {

        if (size == 0) {
            System.out.println("The list is empty.");
        }
        if (head.data == x) {
            head = head.next;
            if (head != null) {
                head.prev = null;
            }
            size--;
            return;
        }

        tmp = head;

        while (tmp != null && tmp.data != x) {
            tmp = tmp.next;
        }

        if (tmp == null) {
            System.out.println("That integer does not exist.");
            return;
        }

        if (tmp.data == x) {
            tmp.prev.next = tmp.next;
            if (tmp.next != null) {
                tmp.next.prev = tmp.prev;
            }
        }
        size--;
    }
    public void printList() {
        while (head != null) {
            System.out.print(head.data + " ");
            head = head.prev;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Numbers nu = new Numbers();

    }
    class Node {
        Node prev;
        Node next;
        int data;

        public void Node(int data) {
            this.data = data;
            next = null;
            prev = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you create your `Node` you're not passing it the `data` variable. Should be `node n = new Node(data);` right?

Comment: I tried it, it won't work for the delete method. I get Incompatible operand types int for numbers.Node.

Comment: You have several logic errors in your code.  The best thing you can do, for your own education, is to step through the code in your IDE debugger one line at a time, examining the variables after each statement to see what is happening.

Comment: You can debug the code, add some logging statements to understand when and why does it throw a NullPointerException.

Comment: you say temp = head , can you tell me where  did you declare tmp and what type of variable is this? Since java does not allow to declare a variable without it's type

Comment: I declared temp before the while loop and was using it to check integers that are not in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and check output

public class Numbers {

```
Node head = null; 
Node tail = null; 
int size = 0;

public void FrontInsert(int data) {
    Node n = new Node(data);
    if (head == null) { // first insert
        head = n;
        tail = n;
    } else {
        n.next = head;
        head.prev = n;
        head = n;

    }
    size++;
}

public void RearInsert(int data) {
    Node n = new Node(data);
    if (head == null) {
        head = n;
        tail = n;

    } else {

        n.prev = tail;
        tail.next = n;
        tail = n;
    }
    size++;
}

public void Delete(int index) { // index is the position to be remove

    if (size == 0) {
        System.out.println("The list is empty."); return;
    }else if(index < 0 || index > size -1){
        System.out.println("Index outOf Bound."); return;
    }

    Node currentNode  = head;
    for(int i = 1; i <= index ; i++){
        currentNode = currentNode.next;
    }
    //remove
    if (index == 0) {
        currentNode.next.prev = null;
        head = currentNode.next;
    } else if (index == size - 1) {
        currentNode.prev.next = null;
        tail = currentNode.prev;
    } else {
        if (currentNode.prev != null) // Ensure its not header
            currentNode.prev.next = currentNode.next;
        if (currentNode.next != null) // Ensure its not tail
            currentNode.next.prev = currentNode.prev;
    }
    size--;
}

public void printList() {
    Node tmp = head;
    while (tmp != null) {
        System.out.print(tmp.data + "  ");
        tmp = tmp.next;
    }
    System.out.println();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Numbers nu = new Numbers();
    nu.FrontInsert(1);nu.printList();
    nu.FrontInsert(2);nu.printList();
    nu.RearInsert(3);nu.printList();
    nu.FrontInsert(4);nu.printList();
    nu.RearInsert(3);nu.printList();
    nu.FrontInsert(4);nu.printList();
    nu.RearInsert(3);nu.printList();
    nu.RearInsert(3);nu.printList();
    nu.FrontInsert(4);nu.printList();
    System.out.println();
    nu.Delete(4);
    nu.printList();
}

class Node {
    Node prev;
    Node next;
    int data;

    public Node(int data) {
        this.data = data;
        next = null;
        prev = null;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Well, your head and tail were mutually exclusive, i mean when you add something to the tail of the list, you were only giving one side reference not both side, you have to says

`tail.next = n; n.prev = tail; and tail = n`.

Here is a working code:

```
public class Numbers {

Node head = null; //Head of the list
Node tail = null; //end of the doubly list    
int size = 0;


public void FrontInsert(int data) {
    Node n = new Node(data);
    if (head == null) {
        head = n;
        tail = head;
    } else {
        n.next = head;
        head.prev = n;
        head = n;

    }
    size++;
}

public void RearInsert(int data) {
    Node n = new Node(data);
    if (head == null) {
        head = n;
        tail = head;
    } else {
        n.next = null;
        tail.next = n;
        n.prev = tail;
        tail = n;
    }
    size++;
}

@SuppressWarnings("null")
public void Delete(int x) {

    if (size == 0) {
        System.out.println("The list is empty.");
        return;
    }
    if (head.data == x) {
        head = head.next;
        if (head != null) {
            head.prev = null;
        }
        size--;
        return;
    }

    Node tmp = head;


    while (true) {
        if(tmp == null)
            break;
        if(tmp.data == x)
            break;
        System.out.println(tmp.data);
        tmp = tmp.next;
    }

    if (tmp == null) {
        System.out.println("That integer does not exist.");
        return;
    }

    if (tmp.data == x) {
        tmp.prev.next = tmp.next;
        if (tmp.next != null) {
            tmp.next.prev = tmp.prev;
        }
    }
    size--;
}
public void printList() {
    while (head != null) {
        System.out.print(head.data + " ");
        head = head.next;
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Numbers nu = new Numbers();
    nu.FrontInsert(2);
    nu.FrontInsert(3);   
    nu.FrontInsert(6);
    nu.RearInsert(8);
    nu.RearInsert(20);
    nu.Delete(8);
    nu.printList(); 
   // System.out.println(nu.head.data + "data");
 //   System.out.println(nu.head.next.data + "data");

}
class Node {
    Node prev;
    Node next;
    private int data;


    public Node(int data) {
        this.data = data;
        next = null;
        prev = null;
    }
}
```

}